# Lua : Storing in a table through a variable name

Tags: lua, lua-table

I understand why this mwe doesn't work but I don't know how make it works.
I'd like to use the variable content as reference name (not the variable name).

```
salade = {}

name = "tomato"

salade.name = "red"

print (salade.tomato)   -- nil, should be red 
print (salade.name)     -- red, should be nil
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the normal table indexing syntax, rather than the `tbl.key` syntactic sugar:

```
salade = {}
name = "tomato"
salade[name] = "red"

print (salade.tomato)   -- red
print (salade.name)     -- nil
```